# How do I extract a loop into a constant time computation?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Is it possible to predetermine variables `x` and `d` to call `initialFunction()` without `while(1)` loop?

```
void function( int xc, int yc, int r, int color ){
    int x = 0;
    int y = r;
    int d = 1-2*r;
    while( 1 ){
        x++;
        d += 4*x-2;
        if( d>0 ){
            initialFunction(x,y,d);
            break;
        }
    }
    while( x>=y ){
        x++;
        d += 4*x-2;
        if( d>0 ){
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `while(1)` can be replaced by `for(;;)`.

Comment: I mean without any kind of unnecessary loop, just bare equations

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "predetermine variables".

Comment: @MikeCAT A bit mean, but kind of funny too. It does answer the question.

Comment: So the question boils down to finding an `x` and `d` for which the sum `i=0 to x` of `4*i-2` satisfies `d>0`

Comment: @dbush I need to know exact value of `x` such that `d>0` and `d` being as small as possible

Comment: its just basic maths.

Comment: Something like x=ceil(sqrt(r-0.5)), d=1-2r+2x^2

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number than can you share your knowledge? Im not omniscient

Comment: so basically a math problem?

Comment: @Dobijasek None of us are, but you could at least try for yourself, instead of expecting to be told the answer. These kind of simple mathematical problems do sometimes need to be solved by programmers, so some practise will do you no harm.

Comment: @john I ask because I tryed it myself for 2 hours and I do not even know how to name this kind of problem to find any clues. Probably its very trivial but like I said, how can I find something if I can not name it.

Comment: @Dobijasek just curious: what is `function` supposed to do?

Comment: btw sorry if my comment was snarky, I didnt mean to say "its trivial" but rather "this is a maths problem, that requires you to use pen and paper, not a problem about code, but one that you should have solved before writing the code" ;)

Comment: Using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%281-2*r+%2B+sum+form+x+%3D+1+to+z+of+%284*x-2%29%29+%3E+0+for+z).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I tryed without any succes. Below @lastchance mention about `triangle number` and this is the part I couldnt find.

Comment: @Dobijasek you do not need to know about triangle numbers to solve it. Its just a shortcut. What you need to know is quadratic equations. Having heard about 2nd order polynomials helps, but is not strictly necessary I think

Comment: anyhow my point is: The lesson to learn here is to do the maths first. Your problem is not the code, but that you wrote the code before having a clear idea of what you need/want to do. The topic of this is not "remove a while loop" but "quadaratic equations" (and as such borderline offtopic here)

Comment: You have no need of quadratic equations here. The triangle numbers are just an arithmetic series 1+2+3+…

Comment: @lastchance and then? the sum is quadratic and OP wants to solve for `1+2+3 ... > 0`

Comment: The OP wants to solve for d>0, which, in this instance amounts to x^2 > r-1/2. No quadratic-equation formula is needed to add up 1+2+3+...+x since it's just an arithmetic series ("average of first and last terms multiplied by number of terms"). It's well-enough known as "triangle numbers" and useful in combinatorics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is trying, in succession, cases with `x=1`, `x=2`, `x=3`, `...`

The `1st` time through, `d` is `1-2r+(4 * 1-2)`

The `2nd` time through, `d` is `1-2r+(4 * 1-2) + (4 * 2-2)`

...

The `x` time through, `d` is `1-2r+4*(sum from 1 to x)-2*x`

With formula for triangle numbers this is `d=1-2r+4*x*(x+1)/2-2x`

which simplifies to `d=1-2r+2x^2`

Then `d>0` implies `2x^2>2r-1` or `x^2>r-1/2`.

So set `x=ceil(sqrt(r-0.5))` and `d=1-2r+2x^2`

Answer (score 8):

The loop performs an iterative computation of `x` and `d`.  You're asking for a closed-form version.  The particular procedure happens to be amenable to expressing `d` as a finite sum of `x` terms, which we can write like so, in mathematical terms:

```
d = 1 - 2r + SUM(i = 1, x) [4i - 2]
```

The `i` in that formula corresponds to the various values that variable `x` takes in your iterative procedure, and the `1 - 2r` is the initial value of `d` in that procedure.  The `x` and `d` are the *final* values of those variables after the iteration (and `r` is the invariant value of `r` for the computation).

A little algebra then gets us to

```
d = 1 - 2r + 4*SUM(i = 1, x) [i] - 2*SUM(i = 1, x) [1]
```

Those two finite sums have well-known solutions.  Applying them gives us

```
d = 1 - 2r + 4x(x+1)/2 - 2x
```

, which we can further reduce to

```
d = 1 - 2r + 2x^2
```

We want the smallest positive value of `x` that makes `d` strictly positive, so we solve

```
1 - 2r + 2x^2 > 0
```

or, equivalently,

```
x^2 > r - 1/2
```

If `r` is less than or equal to 1 then the minimum positive integer `x` satisfying that equation is 1.  Otherwise, we take the positive square root of both sides to get

```
x > sqrt(r - 1/2)
```

We furthermore observe that because `r` is a positive integer,

- the square root is well defined, and
- the square root is not integral.

Therefore the minimum `x` that satisfies the equation is the integer ceiling of the square root of r - 1/2.  We can plug that in to one of the equations above to get the corresponding value of `d`.

Coming back to C, we can express that as

```
if (r <= 1) {
    x = 1;
} else {   
    x = ceil(sqrt(r - 0.5));
}
d = 1 - 2*r + 2*x*x;
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on this code

```
while(1) {
    x++;
    d += 4*x-2;
    if( d>0 ){
        initialFunction(x,y,d);
        break;
    }
}
```

You can write down the formula for `d` after n-th iteration:

```
 d_n = d_0 + 4-2 + 8-2 + 12-2 + 14-2 + ....
     = d_0 +  2  +  6  +  10  +  12  + ...
```

What is added increases linear, thats a 2nd order polynomial:

```
 d_n = d_0 + a + b*n + c*n*n
```

I'll leave it to you to determine the coefficients (you just need to plug in some of the values you know already, eg after `n=1`st iteration the value is `d0+2` which must equal `d_0+a+b+c`) . Once you got them you solve

```
 d_0 + a + b*n + c*n*n == 0
```

for `n`. How you can do this is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation